# How to add some hints on InfiniteProgress() Dialog

Tags: codenameone

I call new InfiniteProgress().showInfiniteBlocking() to prevent the user from entering any keys while my app is processing.
But there is only a circle animating when blocking the screen.
Can I have labels on the InfiniteBlocking screen to show some hints to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is just a transparent dialog as you can see from [the code](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/InfiniteProgress.java#L165-L184). Just create your own version of that method with whatever customization you would like to have.